# Flink - event-time sliding window with missing data in window due to time gaps

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, stream-processing

Suppose I have a stream of stock market trading events, like this:

```
technical1, ALXN, 1/1/2016
technical1, CELG, 1/1/2016
technical2, ALXN, 1/2/2016
technical2, CELG, 1/2/2016
. . . 
technicalN, ALXN, 4/1/2018
technicalN, CELG, 4/1/2018
```

such that technicalN (where N is some number) represents the Nth technical trading entry [Open (float), High(float), Low (float), Close (float), Volume (int)] of end-of-day daily stock market trading data for the given company. (i.e. technical1 for ticker GOOG is different than technical1 for ticker MSFT.) Like:

```
12.52, 19.25, 09.11, 17.54, 120532, GOOG, 1/1/2017
14.37, 29.52, 01.53, 12.96, 627156, MSFT, 1/1/2017
```

(Note that these trading prices/volumes are completely fictitious.)

Let's say that I want to create a window of size 2 with an interval of 1 day so that our data would look something like this:

```
[technical1, GOOG, 12/26/2017; technical2, GOOG, 12/27/2017]
[technical1, MSFT, 12/26/2017; technical2, MSFT, 12/27/2017]
[technical2, GOOG, 12/27/2017; technical3, GOOG, 12/28/2017]
[technical2, MSFT, 12/27/2017; technical3, MSFT, 12/28/2017]
[technical3, GOOG, 12/28/2017; technical4, GOOG, 12/29/2017]
[technical3, MSFT, 12/28/2017; technical4, MSFT, 12/29/2017]
[technical4, GOOG, 12/29/2017; technical5, GOOG, 12/30/2017]
[technical4, MSFT, 12/29/2017; technical5, MSFT, 12/30/2017]
[technical5, GOOG, 12/30/2017; technical6, GOOG, 12/31/2017]
[technical5, MSFT, 12/30/2017; technical6, MSFT, 12/31/2017]
[technical6, GOOG, 12/31/2017; technical7, GOOG, 01/01/2018]
[technical6, MSFT, 12/31/2017; technical7, MSFT, 01/01/2018]
[technical7, GOOG, 01/01/2018; technical8, GOOG, 01/02/2018]
[technical7, MSFT, 01/01/2018; technical8, MSFT, 01/02/2018]
[technical8, GOOG, 01/02/2018; technical9, GOOG, 01/03/2018]
[technical8, MSFT, 01/02/2018; technical9, MSFT, 01/03/2018]
[. . .]
[technicalN, GOOG, 04/01/2018; technicalN+1, GOOG, 04/02/2018]
[technicalN, MSFT, 04/01/2018; technicalN+1, MSFT, 04/02/2018]
. . .
```

This would be nice, but it's problematic because stock market trading dates are not continuous... In other words, if I understand the mechanics of Flink correctly (and I could be wrong), the problem with using an event-time sliding window like this:

```
DataStream<T> input = ...;

// sliding event-time windows
input
.keyBy((TechnicalDataEntry technical) -> technical.ticker)
.window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.day(2), Time.day(1))) // Window size of 2 days, sliding interval of 1 day
.<windowed transformation>(<window function>);
```

on data like that is that the date values are not continuous (meaning that they follow a discrete series that contains discontinuities of one or more missing days) **because there is no stock market data for dates in which the stock market is closed, such as on holidays or weekends**. 
So, with that in mind, our stream would actually end up looking more like this (because trading is closed on 12/30/2017, 12/31/2017, and 01/01/2018):

```
[technical1, GOOG, 12/26/2017; technical2, GOOG, 12/27/2017]
[technical1, MSFT, 12/26/2017; technical2, MSFT, 12/27/2017]
[technical2, GOOG, 12/27/2017; technical3, GOOG, 12/28/2017]
[technical2, MSFT, 12/27/2017; technical3, MSFT, 12/28/2017]
[technical3, GOOG, 12/28/2017; technical4, GOOG, 12/29/2017]
[technical3, MSFT, 12/28/2017; technical4, MSFT, 12/29/2017]
[technical4, GOOG, 12/29/2017; NULL]
[technical4, MSFT, 12/29/2017; NULL]
[NULL; NULL]
[NULL; NULL]
[NULL; NULL]
[NULL; NULL]
[NULL; technical8, GOOG, 01/02/2018]
[NULL; technical8, MSFT, 01/02/2018]
[technical8, GOOG, 01/02/2018; technical9, GOOG, 01/03/2018]
[technical8, MSFT, 01/02/2018; technical9, MSFT, 01/03/2018]
[. . .]
[technicalN, GOOG, 04/01/2018; technicalN+1, GOOG, 04/02/2018]
[technicalN, MSFT, 04/01/2018; technicalN+1, MSFT, 04/02/2018]
```

How do I get my Flink stream to ignore the missing dates (and instead window or join or map together consecutive non-missing dates) so that my stream would look like this instead:

```
[technical1, GOOG, 12/26/2017; technical2, GOOG, 12/27/2017]
[technical1, MSFT, 12/26/2017; technical2, MSFT, 12/27/2017]
[technical2, GOOG, 12/27/2017; technical3, GOOG, 12/28/2017]
[technical2, MSFT, 12/27/2017; technical3, MSFT, 12/28/2017]
[technical3, GOOG, 12/28/2017; technical4, GOOG, 12/29/2017]
[technical3, MSFT, 12/28/2017; technical4, MSFT, 12/29/2017]
[technical4, GOOG, 12/29/2017; technical5, GOOG, 01/02/2018]
[technical4, MSFT, 12/29/2017; technical5, MSFT, 01/02/2018]
[technical5, GOOG, 01/02/2018; technical6, GOOG, 01/03/2018]
[technical5, MSFT, 01/02/2018; technical6, MSFT, 01/03/2018]
[. . .]
[technicalN, GOOG, 04/01/2018; technicalN+1, GOOG, 04/02/2018]
[technicalN, MSFT, 04/01/2018; technicalN+1, MSFT, 04/02/2018]
```

?

(Note: please ignore the way that I'm incrementing the number by the string "technical" (like technical1, technical2, etc.) because, as I mentioned already, that value was just for descriptive purposes in this post and doesn't actually exist in the data. The only way to determine if two trading entries are consecutive is by grouping them by ticker and ordering them by trading date. Let's assume that no duplicate events exist.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your issue is that because there are certains periods when you're not receiving events then the windows won't behave properly since they don't know about the passage of time.

One option you have is to peridiocally emit a watermark like so:

```
streamEnvironment.addSource(new SourceFunction<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void run(final SourceContext<Object> ctx) {
            (...)

            ctx.emitWatermark(new Watermark(timestamp));
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel() {

        }
    })
```

Have in mind that if you receive events prior to the watermark they will be ignored so the periodicity of your watermark emission is a trade-off between "window accuracy" (firing as soon as they can) and being tolerant to late events.